# Implementing 'Search' functionality on website

Tags: c#, mysql, search, full-text-search

I have a website which has thousands of (ever increasing) resources in it. I implemented the usual **Sql Full text Search**  and it was working fine until recently.  I noticed some performance issues with it. I am using MySql Database with C#. NET as the back-end code.

I just need few valuable suggestions from you so that I can take those into account while building a new search strategy for my website.

What can I use to improve performance in the search functionality on my site?

Comment: You need to be **WAY** more specific about your setup / table structure / performance issues / etc...

Comment: They do, yes.  Fortunately, the main issue is that MySQL has only limited full-text search support and it doesn't necessarily scale very well.  The usual solution -- which three people immediately latched onto -- is Lucene.

Comment: As much as I love Lucene - and I do - without knowing what the actual problem is this is akin to suggesting NHibernate / LINQ to someone complaining about his ODBC code being slow

Comment: I think it's more like suggesting MySQL to someone saying their unindexed files are slow for retrieval. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try out;

http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/

Comment: +1, At work, we use lucene and we are very happy with it, I recommend too.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Lucene.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/). It is a high-performance, full-featured text search engine library which was initially written in Java but ported over to .NET. It is a technology suitable for nearly any application that requires full-text search, especially cross-platform.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Lucene.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/). Many websites have text search based on it.